# Spring JPA - Stored Proc where result is not a table

Tags: java, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

We have a project setup and working by accessing Entities and Stored Procs mapped to tables.
However, we have an SP that returns dynamic data, this result set is not a Table/Entity, but a dynamic select query.

The problem I have is that there is no table to map the results to using JPA Repository.

This is "dynamic" results returned from the SP that do not relate to a single table, but are a mix of multiple tables and calculations.
However, JPA is checking during run time and warning that no table with that name exists. If I remove the Table annotation, then the Repository can't be autowired!

Can any one point me in the direction of Docs that hook Spring JPA to an SP that returns data that's NOT an physical table?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to create a repository only for that specific query? You could just add the query to another repository which does have an associated entity. What's the return type for the query, `List<Object[]>`?

Comment: The return type is a known format. I have created a POJO for this List<DocumentRequest>. However, I get an error saying "DocumentRequest" is not a table (It never will be).

Comment: You should edit your question to include some relevant code (like the repository you tried to write). Just describing your situation makes it a bit too abstract.

Comment: I think the problme relates to Mapping QueryTypes to non-managed POJO. I've got his returning data (as Tuples) but this will not cast to the POJO as GenericConversionService throws an error... Am I going to have to Map this by hand? That feels very 2010s

Comment: There's no automagic mapping to generic POJOs, which is why I was asking if you were returning `Object[]` which is the standard "return anything". You might want to have a look at [projections](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-projections). JPA is an entity framework specification, so it's constrained by having to be generic enough to support the different implementations and its primary use case are entities.